QGIS - Convert labels to annotation
I have the following question:
In QGIS 3.26, is there an option to convert labels to annotations, just like ArcMap does?
I have searched and have not found an answer to my question. What I found was that a user posted the following plugin:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ConvertLabels/#plugin-details
"Convert Labels"
But it doesn't work for me either.

Are you using a Geodatabase? or Geopackage?

In QGIS, no, why? but I could use it if necessary to resolve my doubt.

What doesn't for you with the plugin ? did you get an error message ?
